# Filtering, sorting, showing

Tags: feature-request, search, sorting, tag-search

I would like to have an advance filtering and sorting mechanism. How do other people feel about it and how do the makers feel about it?

I would like to filter on:

- tags (and/or)
- If questions are closed
- If questions are negative (downvoted)
- If questions have an accepted answer.
- If questions have no answer.
- If questions have an answer of myself (or better: does NOT have an answer of me)

If would like to sort:

- On date (newest / oldest)
- Polularity (number of upvotes)
- Number of answers

In the overviews I also would like to see:

- If questions are closed (with a symbol, like a red cross, not [closed])
- If questions have an accepted answer (green tick)
- If I have already added an answer.

Comment: I believe the search bar already allows you to do most of that - if you learn how to use it.

Comment: For the last three points, you could probably make a userscript that does exactly that.

Comment: Sound great. I understand there is no user friendly form to fill out?

Answer (score 4):

> tags (and/or)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery

> If questions are closed

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3A1

> If questions are negative (downvoted)

Not possible with the search. You can search for score ≥ 0 or any positive integer. You might be able to write a feature request to have that changed, although I honestly don't see the point in searching for negatively scored questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A0

> If questions have an accepted answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=accepted%3A1

> If questions have no answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0

> If questions have an answer of myself (or better: does NOT have an answer of me)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2304116+is%3Aanswer

For the inverse and anything else, you can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).